# InfoBox enableEventPropagation:true causes scroll to not work

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I have a dynamically added InfoBox on a google map apiv3. When the enableEventPropagation is set to false the scrolling works properly. However if it is set to true, then it will be disabled.

```
requirements
1. Infobox
2. Clickable image inside infobox
3. scrollable div within infobox

new InfoBox({
        content: document.getElementById("infobox-wrapper-hotel"),
        disableAutoPan: false,
        enableEventPropagation: false,


.infoBox #scroll{
  overflow:scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display:block;
  height:250px;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

This is scrolling on a ipad device which is causing issues. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I see why from the documentation....

" and enableEventPropagation properties have no affect until the current InfoBox is closed and a new one is opened."

Does anyone know a way around this?